# Read encoded characters from socket not working when export to JAR

Tags: java, eclipse

If i run as a java application in eclipse there is no problem but if i export as a runnable jar file the project i get encoding problem ?

if it runs from eclipse i can read the char "ş" that is coming from the server via socket. If it runs as a runnable jar i can't read the char "ş"

How can i fix this ?

EDIT

```
public class Start {

     public static void main(String[] args) {


               byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
               Socket socket = null;
               InputStream in = null;

               try {
                    socket = new Socket("11.11.11.11");
                    in = socket.getInputStream();

               } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
               }

               try {
                    in.read(buff);

               } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
               } 

               System.out.println(new String(buff));




    }

}
```

Comment: The encoding problem may have to do with the setting of the terminal you use, by the way. The code could work fine

Comment: first close your opened `streams` and are you getting any stack trace any `output` ??

Comment: i don't get any stacktrace i get "Åÿ" instead of "ş"

Comment: i get bytes of "-60 -70" for char "ğ" both of them(in eclipse or runnable jar in windows) but in eclipse i read as "ğ".

if i run as a runnable jar in windows i read  "Åÿ"

Comment: did you try change your console format i mean is it in `utf-8`??

Answer (score 2):

```
new String(buff)
```

creates the string using the default encoding for the current platform. This may be different in Eclipse and outside of Eclipse.

Instead use

```
new String(buff, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

to specify that the byte array should always be treated as UTF-8 (assuming it is UTF-8 that you are receiving)

Also don't forget to close your streams.

Comment: Yes in eclipse i don't need define charset but outside of eclipse i have to define it.